# unable to find "Add name" in contacts of gmail user page using xpath in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

While adding a new contact to my gmail account

When i try to locate an element "Add name" in gmail -> contacts page of any user

I'm not able find exact xpath for this element and unable to perform events like click or sendKeys using selenium webdriver . Any help is appreciated

Thanks,
Audi

Answer (score 1):

This has been said many times; do not try and automate Gmail.

Presumably you fit into one of the following;

- If you are trying to learn automation then there are far more friendly sites than gmail. It is very dynamic and a challenge for experienced automators.
- If you are trying to automate gmail to automate a task you perform on your account, then look at the GMail API.  Selenium is a horribly inefficient way to automate a repetitive manual task
- If you are trying to automate GMail as part of your testing of another site, reconsider if you really need to. Is this going beyond the boundaries of the AUT?  If you need to extract info from a generates email or it is a pertinent test, then consider using the GMail API for stability and efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the css selector. In the browser right click on the web element  and choose inspect element. If there is an ID or unique class do: FindElement(By.cssSelector ("selector ")).sendKeys(" string").

The above is written in Java.